# Multiple markers not showing in Google Maps with Javascript API v3?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'd like to know how to put multiple markers for Google Maps using Javascript API v3.

I tried the solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621991/multiple-markers-in-googe-maps-api-v3-that-link-to-different-pages-when-clicked), but it does not work for me for some reason:

```
var directionDisplay;

function initialize() {        
  var myOptions = { zoom: 9, center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.81940575,-73.95647955), mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
  setMarkers(map, properties);

  var properties = [
    ['106 Ft Washington Avenue',40.8388485,-73.9436015,'Mjg4'],
  ];

  function setMarkers(map, buildings) {
    var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage('map_marker.png', new google.maps.Size(19,32), new google.maps.Point(0,0), new google.maps.Point(10,32));
    var shadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage('map_marker_shadow.png', new google.maps.Size(28,32), new google.maps.Point(0,0), new google.maps.Point(10,32));
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds;
    for (var i in buildings) {
      var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(buildings[i][1], buildings[i][2]);
      bounds.extend(myLatLng);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: myLatLng, map: map, shadow: shadow, icon: image, title: buildings[i][0] });
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() { window.location = ('detail?b=' + buildings[i][3]); });
    }
    map.fitBounds(bounds);  
  }
}
</script>
```

Could anyone kindly explain why this doesn't work for me?

Comment: Welcome to SO. What errors do you get? At which point is initialize() called?

Comment: The map does not show any markers at all and it displays an area in the Winslow Reef. No where by Washington as I expect. I would like to display multiple markers. Please help

Comment: initialize() is called on the body

Answer (score 3):

This question is already a few months old, but I noticed that it remained unanswered. I guess the OP already found a way through this, but let me attempt an answer for the sake of completeness.

---

I can spot a few major problems in your code above:

1. First of all, you are trying to pass the `properties` array to the `setMarkers()` function, before `properties` is defined. Therefore `setMarkers()` will receive `undefined` for the second argument, which is why nothing is showing on your map.
2. Then, you are having [a very common closure problem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops.3a_A_common_mistake) in that `for in` loop. Variables enclosed in a closure share the same single environment, so by the time the `click` callback from the `addListener` is called, the loop will have run its course and the `i` variable will be left pointing to the last value it had when loop ended.
3. In addition, you have a dangling comma in the array literal, which can cause a syntax error in some browsers.

---

To fix the first problem, simply define the `properties` array before calling `setMarkers()`:

```
var properties = [
  ['106 Ft Washington Avenue',40.8388485,-73.9436015,'Mjg4'],
];

setMarkers(map, properties);
```

You can then solve the closure problem with even more closures, using a function factory:

```
function makeClickCallback(buildings, i) {  
   return function() {  
      window.location = ('detail?b=' + buildings[i][3]);
   };  
} 

for (var i in buildings) {
   // ...

   google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', 
                                 makeClickCallback(buildings, i);
}
```

This can be quite a tricky topic, if you are not familiar with how closures work. You may to check out the following Mozilla article for a brief introduction:

- [Working with Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Closures)

Then you may want to make sure to remove the dangling comma in your array literal:

```
var properties = [
  ['106 Ft Washington Avenue',40.8388485,-73.9436015,'Mjg4']  // no comma
];
```

In addition, note that since there is just one element in your `properties` array, you will only get one marker on the map. I'm not sure if the other elements were removed for the sake of this example, but if it wasn't, simply add more locations like this:

```
var properties = [
  ['106 Ft Washington Avenue',40.8388485,-73.9436015,'Mjg4'],
  ['Another Location',50.505050,-75.505050,'Mjg5']
];
```